# polynomial regression in julia - glm

Tags: statistics, julia, linear-regression

Is it possible to do polynomial regression in the GLM-package within Julia? 
Considering the similarity with R syntax, I had hoped that

```
 fit(LinearModel, @formula(y ~ poly(x,5)), dataset)
```

would work (for fitting a degree 5 polynomial). It does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StatsModels.jl does not provide a `poly()` function, but their documentation does provide [a complete example](https://juliastats.github.io/StatsModels.jl/stable/internals/#An-example-of-custom-syntax:-poly-1) that shows how you can add your own `poly()` function that will work inside the `@formula` macro.

Comment: Maybe file an issue for exporting such a poly function? Polynomials are common enough for this to make sense, no?

Comment: Ok, that resolves it. I agree that it would be very useful to have this exported. Quite honestly, don't know exactly how to file this issue.

Comment: This is currently shown only to illustrate the flexibility of `@formula`. A proper implementation aimed at end users still needs to be finished and exports.

Answer (score 6):

Although you are explicitly asking for a GLM.jl solution, let me nonetheless point out the straightforward solution using [Polynomials.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Polynomials.jl):

```
using Polynomials
polyfit(x, 5)
```

See [`polyfit`](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Polynomials.jl#polyfitx-y-nlengthx-1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am also interested in standard-errors, so that's why I included GLM. It is not terribly hard to code this myself, but I am a bit surprised that it seems not to be available within GLM.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an issue with GLM directly, but with the underlying `@formula` macro from StatsModels.jl - as far as I know, there's currently no syntax for generating polynomials up to a prespecified order.

You can however apply Julia functions columnwise within the formula macro, so up to a limited order it's probably easiest to just type it out like

```
using GLM, DataFrames

y = [0.1*x^2 - 0.5*x for x ∈ 1:100]
x = collect(1:100)
df = (y = y, x = x)

fit(LinearModel, @formula(y ~ x + x^2), df)
```

Note that this doesn't require having x squared as a column in the dataframe - the `@formula` can generate the required regressors on the fly in the model matrix.

You can also generate formulas programmatically, as described in the docs [here](https://juliastats.github.io/StatsModels.jl/stable/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically-1) - the problem is that this doesn't yet work for passing Julia functions as shown above in the `@formula` macro. I believe work is ongoing on this, so stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful to know.